# python - Run Application out of Virtual File System

Tags: python, windows, filesystems, dokan

A quick question for anyone who knows the answer. I'm doing with with virtual file systems and python. I have an EXE file within my file system, is it possible to run this application without having to expose the file system with something like Dokan?

If not possible, is there a way to expose the file system without the need of drivers/admin privileges like Dokan requires in Windows?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No way (without some very deep kernel-mode hacking). You need to have a filesystem visible to the OS via the driver stack in order to run an EXE from it. One option is to create a hidden filesystem or map the virtual file system to the directory on existing NTFS drive (eg. our Callback File System lets you do this), but in any case a kernel-mode driver is required.

There's one more option possible but I didn't see viable implementations of it: create an SMB server module and create a network mapped drive, which is connected to this SMB server.

Comment: Does Callback File System allow you to do this without the need of UAC or a driver?

Comment: As I wrote, the driver is required in any case.